# jQuery click event handlers don't work after loading html page with load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am loading several html pages on an index page depending on what link was clicked.I have a problem with the links that have asocietted click event handlers.It seems that after the jQuery loads the html file the links in that html do not have there click event handlers binded to them.
Here is my code:

This is the html for one of the links that does not work:

```
<a href="#" id="NavContactPage" data-sectionId="Skills">skills</a>
```

This is the jquery code asocieted with it:

```
$("nav a , a.first_anchor , a#NavContactPage").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("data-sectionId");
    var link = "load/" + id + ".html";

    $("div#Content").load(link , function(){
        $("section#" + id).fadeIn(); 
        if(id === "Portfolio"){
            $('div.slide').cycle('fade');
        }
        if(id === "Home"){
            $("#jcycleslider").cycle({
                fx: mtransition,
                easing: easing,
                before: onBefore,
                after: onAfter,
                speed: mpace,
                timeout: mnext,
                sync: msync,
                randomizeEffects:0,
                pager:'#jslider_nav'
            })
            $("#jslider_nav a").text("");
        }    
    })      
    return false;
})
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does the new page (the one loaded) has a #NavContactPage link? does it overrides the previous link?

Comment: yes it has #NavContactPage

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$("selector").click(...)` only registers the callbacks for the `click` event to the elements that where visible to jQuery at the time you did the query. So for newly added elements, that match this selector, the callback will not be applied.

You either need to registrate the callbacks to the newly added elements again or you need to use:

`$(document).on('click',"nav a , a.first_anchor , a#NavContactPage", ... );`

Instead of using document as root it is recommend to use e.g. the element where you are loading the content to as root e.g. `$("div#Content").on( .... );`

Answer (score 7):

As i understand it, you should use delegation with .on():

```
$(document).on('click',"nav a , a.first_anchor , a#NavContactPage",function(){...}
```

Answer (score 4):

came across this problem when I was using the .load() function to import html into my main page. I put this inside my ready function and it worked for me

```
$(document).on('click','#btninsertrequest',function(){
alert("yes");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are u binding ur events on jquery ready ?

Your event binding code should be inside and use on instead of click. I think that should solve ur problem.

```
$(function(){

  // Bind event here

});
```